# javafx mediaview only the audio is playing

Tags: java, video, javafx

Im trying to embed a video in a website to a mediaview of a simple javafx application. Ive got a sample code which I used as my javafx code. It opens the scene and plays the audio but wont play the video. How can I make it play the audio? Im using netbeans IDE 8.0.2,JavaFx 8 and scene builder 2.0
The Code ive tried is below.
Thanx in advanced.

```
@FXML MediaView mdv;
Media media;
public static MediaPlayer mpl;
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    media=new Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv");
    mpl=new MediaPlayer(media);
    mpl.setAutoPlay(true);
    mdv=new MediaView(mpl);
    mpl.play();
    mpl.setOnError(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println("Current Error: " + mpl.getError());
        }
    });
}
```

This is how I load the children to the stage

```
public class Production extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Vdo.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

the FXML Ive got after creating the GUI from scene builder is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
fx:controller="production.VdoController">
   <children>
      <MediaView fx:id="mdv" fitHeight="300.0" fitWidth="300.0" layoutX="125.0"  layoutY="85.0" />
      <Button layoutX="235.0" layoutY="51.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: How are you adding the `MediView` to your scene?

Comment: I load this fxml in the main class as a scene using FXML Loader.

Comment: FXMLs do not contain scene, I am asking you how do you add the content of the FXML to the scene.

Comment: I have edited the code with the main method to load the fxml

Comment: Can you add the FXML to the question as well. I can see where you are going wrong, but I would like to give a complete solution with your FXML.

Comment: I added the FXML to the question too :) Do you think its a problem with the type of the video not supporting javafx?

Answer (score 3):

You are re-initializing the MediaView that has been initialized by the `FXMLoader`. Never do this, because you will loose the reference to the original node.

You should just set the MediaPlayer to the MediaView instead of re-initializing it by using the [setMediaPlayer()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaView.html#setMediaPlayer-javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer-).

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    media=new Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv");
    mpl=new MediaPlayer(media);
    mpl.setAutoPlay(true);
    mdv.setMediaPlayer(mpl);
    mpl.play();
}
```

Comment: Hey @AchalaWeerasooriya please accept the answers you got for your questions, iff they have solved your problem.